# asp.net ckeditorContor unable to get content using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using ckeditor(dll) in asp.net appliacation.

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="editorabc" TabIndex="12" BasePath="/adds/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

How can i fetch the content  using jquery like

```
alert($("#<%=editorabc.ClientID%>").val());
```

it shows empty popup.

or 
it is not wokring

```
alert($("#<%=editorabc.ClientID%>").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this dll one and i was using this instruction

```
CKEDITOR.instances.<%=editorabc.ClientID%>.getData();
```

Hope it workks for you